# Como puedo extraer de un cadena, un carácter que se encuentra en el medio y que es de diferentes largos en SQL Developer?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito sacar el apellido paterno de la persona, pero tienen diferentes largos cada nombre, como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido user192345 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: El problema no es la longitud, por que podrías separar por espacios, el tema es que no puedes asegurar en que lugar aparece el apellido que buscas, imagina personas con más de un nombre, con un solo apellido, etc. Básicamente es un problema sin solución completa.

Answer (score 1):

Dada la estructura con la cual se conforman los nombres completos en general en los paises latinos es bastante complejo obtener el apellido paterno con exactitud con la estructura de la tabla como tu la tienes actualmente.

Te recomiendo dividir en más columnas tu tabla

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`employees` 
ADD COLUMN `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL AFTER `NOMBREEMP`,
ADD COLUMN `paterno` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL AFTER `nombre`,
ADD COLUMN `materno` VARCHAR(45) NULL AFTER `paterno`;
```

Posteriormente unas consultas que rellenen los campos, por ejemplo el de nombre quedaría algo así

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET = nombre
    (SELECT substring(NOMBREEMP, 0, charindex(' ', NOMBREEMP, 2)) from EMPLOYEES)
```

Luego de rellenar los 3 nuevos campos generados aún deberas revisar a mano y registro por registro que la información sea correcta para poder garantizar que las estructuras de los nombres esten correctas.